# Learning Functional analysis in one month.

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning

Background: Master in Engineering, applied physics.
Now: New phd student in applied math.
Goal: Pass functional analysis with good grades.

I have not had so much time for studies period 
since there were many conferences and teaching. But now I have 1 month to study really hard. The course is 15 points CET. (20 weeks half time). Since I'm not used to this kind of theoretical math studies I miss some basic background skills (I recently relearnt Bessel's inequality, and had no idea what an uncountable sum was before yesterday)

I passed an Topology exam with good grades last spring so I don't have to start from scratch.
I have also read 75% of the pages in the book and done half of the exercises we have with mixed success. 
The book is Peter Lax's.
Some old exams can be found exams:
http://www.maths.lth.se/utbildning/nf/courses/linfuncan/2012ht12/
There will also be an take home exam. And an oral exam.

Any ideas and recommendations?
I have no problem to study really hard.
How would you distribute the time?
Solve exercises, learn theorems, iterate both?

Thanks
(sorry for bad spelling, English is not my first language and im writing on a phone.)

Comment: I think learning FA in one month is quite difficult , if not for others at least for me .

Comment: I'm learning it for three years and can't say I understand it much.

Comment: My goal is obviously not to be an expert. Rather to be as good as posible, under the given time limt